# Validação de campos no Lumen 5.5

Tags: validação, lumen

Na versão 5.2 do Lumen a seguinte validação no Controller está funcionando:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'nome' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'cpf' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Idem a seguinte View:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0) {
    <div>
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error){
                    echo("<li>". $error . "</li>");
                 }
            @endforeach     
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Ocorre que na versão 5.5 do Lumen não está funcionando.

> O seguinte erro é apresentado:1/1) ErrorException Undefined variable: errors in cadastroPessoas.php (line 8) at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns{closure}(8, 'Undefined variable: errors', 'C:\wamp64\www\blog\resources\views\cadastroPessoas.ph‌​p', 8, array('__path' => 'C:\wamp64\www\blog\resources\views/cadastroPessoas.php‌​', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application)), 'obLevel' => 1, '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application))) in cadastroPessoas.php (line 8) at include('C:\wamp64\www\blog\resources\views\cadastroPe‌​ssoas.php

Comment: É apresentado algum erro? Ativou o DEBUG?

Comment: O seguinte erro é apresentado:1/1) ErrorException
Undefined variable: errors
in cadastroPessoas.php (line 8)
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(8, 'Undefined variable: errors', 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\blog\\resources\\views\\cadastroPessoas.php', 8, array('__path' => 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\blog\\resources\\views/cadastroPessoas.php', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application)), 'obLevel' => 1, '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application)))
in cadastroPessoas.php (line 8)
at include('C:\\wamp64\\www\\blog\\resources\\views\\cadastroPessoas.php

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não vejo como pode ser duplicata, isso porque o erro não é com a validação, mas sim um erro de sintaxe e outro motivo é que o Lumen e Laravel apesar de compartilharem o mesmo ecossistema, eles tem a camada da 'aplicação' um pouco diferente, visando que a intenção do Lumen é ser bem mais *leve* que o Laravel, logo as configurações dele podem variar, como por exemplo a configuração do *middleware*, creio que o autor tenha esquecido de adicionar `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession` (obrigatório para que disponibilize globalmente a variavel `$errors`).

Comment: @FernandoI.Kobayashi resposta editada, veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/246481/3635, leia a parte que escrevi *"Nota importante sobre $errors nas views do Laravel/Lumen"*

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na parte Laravel e Lumen há bastante controvérsias em relação a desempenho e funcionalidades, vou retirar o voto de duplicata, porque, quem fez a pergunta colocou agora a mensagem de erro de variável não definida.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic entendo, mas só queria dizer que independente de ter ou não informado a mensagem de erro, não havia indícios de duplicidade, o único indicio antes do AP informar a mensagem de erro é que haviam possíveis erros de sintaxe quanto ao uso do "Blade" (o que poderiam ou não ocasionar a falha, resumindo seria mais preciso votar como *"erro de digitação"*). Obrigado ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pra mim veio em primeiro tempo que havia um problema na hora de chamar a validação e a resposta associada de duplicidade tinha a explicação que aparentemente ele precisava. Obrigado você !

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento , em relação a nota  pt.stackoverflow.com/a/246481/3635, era assim na versão 5.2 do Lumen.  Agradeço pela ajuda que estão me dando,

Answer (score 1):

Não esta funcionando é muito ambíguo, provavelmente deve estar ocorrendo 500 internal erro server (se o DEBUG estiver desligado) ou esta exibindo uma exception.

Está me parecendo que é uma série de **erros de digitação**:

Tem um `{` que não é necessário, em "Views" isso não é usado:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0) { <--- ISTO
...
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error){ <--- ISTO
```

e `}`:

```
    echo("<li>". $error . "</li>");
 } <--- ISTO
```

e talvez `echo` também não funcione (nem tem sentido, mesmo que funcione, usar echo, afinal todo o resto não precisou)

Deve ser assim:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach     
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Faça os exemplos sempre conforme a documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

> **Nota:** não sei se `$errors` funciona com `count()`, mas no exemplo está com `->any()`, então se o script ainda falhar, troque por
>
> ```
> @if ($errors->any())
>     <div>
>         <ul>
>             @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
>                 <li>{{ $error }}</li>
>             @endforeach     
>         </ul>
>     </div>
> @endif
> ```

---

### Nota importante sobre $errors nas views do Laravel/Lumen

Para que `$errors` esteja disponível é necessário adicionar ao middleware o `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession`, então vá até `bootstrap/app.php` e adicione isto:

```
$app->middleware([
   Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
]);
```

Assim o `$errors` ficará "global", caso não tiver adicionado o Lumen irá disparar o erro:

> ErrorException Undefined variable: errors

Comment: Agora aparece o seguinte erro: RuntimeException
Session store not set on request.
in Request.php (line 414)
at Request->session()
in ShareErrorsFromSession.php (line 42)
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 149)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 32)
at Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)

Comment: @FernandoI.Kobayashi vou tetar aqui, assim que possivel eu lhe aviso

Comment: Na versão 5.2, acrescentei:  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, agora aparece o erro: BindingResolutionException
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\Manager
in Container.php (line 933)
at Container->unresolvablePrimitive(object(ReflectionParameter))
in Container.php (line 871)
at Container->resolvePrimitive(object(ReflectionParameter))
in Container.php (line 812)
@GuilhermeNascimento

Answer (score -1):

O Lumen não tem suporte a validação de campos por Requisição então por si a variável `$errors` não existe.

Documentação Oficial
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation

Só para lembrar o Lumen ele é uma versão micro da framework Laravel então algumas funções do próprio Laravel não irão funcionar no Lumen

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).